# Why does chan not deadlock in goroution?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main
func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    go pump(ch1) // pump hangs
}
func pump(ch chan int) {
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
}
```

Why is it that there is nothing wrong with writing a corruption? Blocking the main process will deadlock

Comment: Nothing is blocking the main goroutine, there is no deadlock.

Comment: As previous comment points out, the program does not deadlock ([test it here](https://play.golang.org/p/ycgrWmFfGNE)).  If there's a deadlock in your actual code, then edit the question to include that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the main() function exits and terminates the program while the pump() goroutine is blocked writing to the channel.

I think this code does what you expect:

```
package main
func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go pump(ch1, done) // pump hangs
    <-done // wait for pump
}
func pump(ch chan int, done chan struct{}) {
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2 // never reached
    close(done) // never reached
}
```

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox778506014/main.go:7 +0xc0

goroutine 4 [chan send]:
main.pump(0x1043a080, 0x1043a0c0)
    /tmp/sandbox778506014/main.go:10 +0x40
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox778506014/main.go:6 +0xa0
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FTFPOBCm4G_0

Comment: If I don't quit giving him a time.sleep, it won't deadlock

Comment: Why is it that there is nothing wrong with writing a corruption? Blocking the main process will deadlock

Comment: on your first question, it blocks, but you just don't see it. main is sleeping, pump is blocked waiting for someone to receive the value from the chan, then suddenly main wakes up and exits. In Everton's example (which is the correct way to demonstrate the problem) main will not quit until pump has finished (and closed the chan), but pump is waiting for someone to read the values. therefore the runtime understands the deadlock and informs you.